# SubItems is not a member of ListViwItem

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview

I want to add my Listview data to another database table. I went through some tutorials & found following solution. However it keeps showing the error :

> "SubItems is not a member of ListViewItem"

```
Private Sub orderButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles orderButton.Click
    Try
        For Each item As ListViewItem In myCart.Items
            Dim sql As New StringBuilder
            sql.AppendLine(" INSERT INTO newMedicinesOrders ")
            sql.AppendLine(" ( ")
            sql.AppendLine(" ,medicineName")
            sql.AppendLine(" ,power")
            sql.AppendLine(" ,form")
            sql.AppendLine(" ,fQuantity")
            sql.AppendLine(" ,iQuantity")
            sql.AppendLine(" ,type")
            sql.AppendLine(" ,cost")
            sql.AppendLine(" ) ")
            sql.AppendLine(" VALUES ")
            sql.AppendLine(" ( ")
            sql.AppendLine(" ,'" & item.SubItems(1).Text & "' ")
            sql.AppendLine(" ,'" & power.Text & "' ")
            sql.AppendLine(" ,'" & Form.Text & "' ")
            sql.AppendLine(" ,'" & fQuantity.Text & "' ")
            sql.AppendLine(" ,'" & iQuantity.Text & "' ")
            sql.AppendLine(" ,'" & Type.Text & "' ")
            sql.AppendLine(" ,'" & iCost.Text & "' ")
            sql.AppendLine(" ,'" & Type.Text & "' ")
            sql.AppendLine(" ) ")
            Dim command As New MySqlCommand
            command.CommandText = sql.ToString
            command.Connection = con2
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write(ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Correct, [ListViewItem from System.Web.Ui.Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listviewitem(v=vs.110).aspx) has no property named SubItems, [here an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863956/cant-access-subitems-in-listview-while-looping) on how to work with ListView in asp.net

Comment: @Steve what is the solution?

Comment: This looks like a Windows Form app-  use square brackets: item.SubItems[1].Text

Comment: This is VB code. The syntax is correct

Comment: @BharatGupta Why does the tags say c# and vb.net? Which is it supposed to be?

Comment: OP has tagged it wrong :P. It should be VB.Net

Answer (score 0):

This is for C#. Please look here:

[Getting SubItem from listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12473701/getting-subitem-from-listview)

You need to use:

```
item.SubItems[1].Text
```

But I notice your tag is for c# and vb.net and your code is actually vb.net.

Comment: I have code in both. But any of them if get what is the error then it will reslove for both

Comment: The way I have done seems to be correct in terms of vb.net

Comment: @StupidRomeo Have you debugged your code and set a breake point in the loop and examined the **item** object?