# Eval In code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, eval, code-behind

In this code I am trying to take the control "Label" with ID "Label", this work but also I want to take the current "AuthorUserID" field from Entity Data Source I know i can do this with `<%# Eval("AuthorUserID" %>)`  but I want to take this field in code behind method, in this case in "ChatListView_ItemDataBound" method.

How to take the current field ("AuthorUserID") in code behind?

Code-behind:

```
protected void ChatListView_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        if (e.Item.FindControl("Label") != null)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Markup:

```
 <asp:ListView ID="ChatListView" runat="server" DataSourceID="EntityDataSourceUserPosts" OnItemDataBound="ChatListView_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="post">
            <div class="postHeader">
                <h2><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
                    Text= '<%# Eval("Title")  + " by " + this.GetUserFromPost((Guid?)Eval("AuthorUserID")) %>' ></asp:Label></h2>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label" runat="server" Text="" Visible="True"></asp:Label>
                <div class="dateTimePost">
                   <%# Eval("PostDate")%>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="postContent">
                <%# Eval("PostComment") %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: Why do you want to pass this? If you just want to format it or do some condition- then create a function say MyFunc in aspx like <%# MyFunc(Eval("PostDate")) %> and in code behind write functions like string MyFunc(object dt) {}

Comment: I am trying to set e.Item.FindControl("Label") to visible = true if the current logged user id is the same as the author id of the content. But your idea sounds good I will try it.

Comment: You can use `Eval("AuthorUserID")` in Code Behind just like you do in your mark up file if it's in a `DataBound` context.

Answer (score 3):

Try this. Change Markup as

```
<asp:Label ID="Label" runat="server" 
        Text="" 
        Visible='<%# CheckIfAuthorIsUser(Eval("AuthorID")) %>'>
</asp:Label>
```

And on code-behind, do this

```
protected bool CheckIfAuthorIsUser(object authorID)
{
    if(authorID == null){ return false;}
    //else compare the passed authorid parameter with the logged in userid and return the appropriate boolean value

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per our comments may be this code may help

Create some property in page that will return say UserID and then

```
<ItemTemplate>

  <asp:Label ID="lbl" Visible='<%# UserID == Convert.ToInt32(Eval("AuthorID")) %>' />

</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reach to the Row data using the `ListViewItemEventArgs e`

```
protected void ChatListView_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
        {
            if (e.Item.FindControl("Label") != null)
            {
               var AuthorUserID = (string)e.Item.DataItem.e.Item.DataItem.AuthorUserID ;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Note**
I don't know if you bounded `class object` or a `datatable`, if you bounded a data table you should take care of casting the data which stored in `DataItem`

Basically the `e.Item.DataItem` hold the data which comes from your data source

For further information look at:

- [Get data being bound to ListView on DataBound event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858001/get-data-being-bound-to-listview-on-databound-event)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Add data key to your ListView

```
<asp:ListView ID="ChatListView" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="ChatListView_ItemDataBound"
        DataKeyNames="AuthorUserID">
```

And get that key in Code behind

```
string AuthorUserID = ChatListView.DataKeys[e.Item.DataItemIndex].Value.ToString();
```